# Regular Expression Match after double space, and before comma

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match the bolded portion of the below String, which would represent a city.

1795 New Test Dr  **Test TEst Wildwood**,  MI  48769-1100

There are two spaces between Dr and Test, the starting portion should happen after those double spaces, and end before the comma.

I feel like I am very close to having this correct but can't quite get it 100%, as it is including the white space characters before **Test**.

```
(?=\s{2})[\w+\s]*[^,]
```

The above is what I have so far, also the many other alternatives did not work either they still include the  white space characters I do not want at the beginning.

I feel like I missing something simple, but even after looking many places I cannot seem to find the regex that would match this pattern.

Also I know this can be easily accomplished with split and substrings, but the requirement is a regex unfortunately, as this is for a database driven automation application and the format should be able to change on the fly without requiring a deploy due to code changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a look-*behind* for the spaces rather than a look-ahead, as you want the match to start immediately after them. From that point on, you can simply do a greedy match for anything that is not a comma:

```
(?<=\s{2})[^,]*
```

The `*` is greedy and will consume as many characters as it can, ending the match immediately before the comma.

Comment: Well this works in general, but the issue I am seeing as that it will match other Strings in this as well. Meaning I think a requirement should be that if I look ahead from the starting point(double spaces) and there is a comma, I should include everything before otherwise it shouldn't match.

Comment: So would a look ahead take care of this issue I am seeing?

Comment: (?<=\s{2})([\w+\s]*(?=,)), this is what I came up with. See any issues with it?

Comment: @broot02 The `[\w+\s]` is suspect - that's a character class that will match any _single_ character that is either a word character (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`), a plus sign, or a space character. But generally, your regex should match pretty much the same as mine, except that mine allows for other (non-comma) punctuation and non-ascii characters (such as é) between the double space and the comma whereas yours doesn't - yours will fail to match at all if it encounters non-`\w` characters such as hyphens.

Comment: Good point on the hyphens, the intention of this is too match a city. But if they say include a number or really anything I don't care Garbage in Garbage out as far as I am concerned.

Comment: (?<=\s{2})(.*(?=,)), thoughts? I appreciate the help this regex has been messing with my head for a while...

Comment: @broot02 that's similar, the difference would show up if the string contains more than one comma.  My `(?<=\s{2})[^,]*` would match everything from the double-space up to the _first_ comma it finds, whereas your `(?<=\s{2}).*(?=,)` would match everything up to the _last_ comma in the string, including any other intervening commas.  You could change the `.*` (greedy) to a `.*?` (reluctant) to make it stop at the first comma.

Answer (score 0):

`\s` actually also matches whitespace other than space, which may or may not be not be what you what.

How about `^.*?  ([^,]*).*$`.  That's a non-greedy match at the beginning of the line `^.*?`, followed by two literal spaces , then capturing everything that isn't a comma, then matching everything else to the end of the line.

Be aware, though, that when I copy and paste your example text, it does not contain two spaces.  This might be causing you problems, or it's just a transcription issue and your original has the two spaces.